# Creating editText beneath drawable programmatically

Tags: java, android, xml, android-edittext, android-drawable

I have an editText: @+id/editText1 which I'd like to instantiate beneath R.drawable.sqwhite after my onClick method

My problem is the drawable isn't created via XML - and I'm not sure exactly how to get my editText1 to appear directly beneath R.drawable.sqwhite

### JAVA:

```
public void onClickAddImage(View v) {
    addNewImageToScreen();
}

public void addNewImageToScreen() {
    int resourceId = R.drawable.sqwhite;
    addNewTextToScreen();
    int m = mImageCount % 3;

    if (m == 1)
        resourceId = R.drawable.sqdrk;

    else if (m == 2)
        resourceId = R.drawable.sqwhite;
    addNewImageToScreen(resourceId);

}

private void addNewTextToScreen() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    et.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    if (isErase) {
        tx.setText(et.getText().toString());
    } else {
        tx.setText("");
        et.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    isErase = !isErase;
}


public void addNewImageToScreen(int resourceId) {
    if (mLastNewCell != null)
        mLastNewCell.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    et.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    FrameLayout imageHolder = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.image_source_frame);
    if (imageHolder != null) {
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                Gravity.CENTER);
        ImageCell newView = new ImageCell(this);
        newView.setImageResource(resourceId);
        imageHolder.addView(newView, lp);
        newView.mEmpty = false;
        newView.mCellNumber = -1;
        mLastNewCell = newView;
        mImageCount++;

        // Have this activity listen to touch and click events for the view.
        newView.setOnClickListener(this);
        newView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
        newView.setOnTouchListener(this);

    }
}
```

### XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.example.project.DragLayer xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:launcher="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.android.launcher"
    android:id="@+id/drag_layer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1.0" >

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/image_grid_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:background="@color/grid_background"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:horizontalSpacing="2dip"
                android:numColumns="@integer/num_columns"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                android:verticalSpacing="2dip" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/bottom_part"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/black"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="1.0" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_add_image"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:onClick="onClickAddImage"
                    android:text="Add image" />

                <com.example.project.DeleteZone
                    android:id="@+id/delete_zone_view"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/delete_zone" />

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/image_source_frame"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5" >

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >



                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/editText1"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                            <requestFocus />
                        </EditText>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
                              android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                            android:text="" />
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </FrameLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</com.example.project.DragLayer>
```

### SCREENSHOT:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the code for `addNewImageToScreen(resourceId)`?

Comment: Done - if there's anything just let me know!

Comment: I'm having a bit trouble understanding your code. In the XML file, why do you have an ImageView with no id above the EditText with id `editText1`? Is this the ImageView you want to be above the EditText?

Comment: You can delete it - it does nothing at the moment (it was left over from some troubleshooting I tried)

Comment: What I would have done in this case is actually keep the ImageView and assign to it an id in the XML file, specify in the XML file that the ImageView should go above the EditText, then programmatically change the drawable/image in this ImageView from the java code.

Comment: That's actually what I tried here:
http://pastebin.com/XhcJ9RxP can you show me what I'll need to do in java?

Comment: I'll gladly accept your answer if you'd like to provide one...

Comment: I'm trying to, don't worry :-)

Comment: Here is the java code that does with what I suggested:
`ImageView imgv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.tile);
Drawable draw = getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.name_of_my_drawable);
imgv.setImageDrawable(draw);`

Comment: Can you show what I'll need to do in XML? I'm working on it now and it isn't working (I'm combining your XML suggestions with your Java suggestions too)

Comment: Also - I'm having a few other issues with this build as well... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20913058/android-xml-layout-parameters-do-not-function-as-expected